# Running a module workaround python "Scalene"

Tags: python, memory, scalene

I am trying to debug a memory leak in a module using Scalene.

Unfortunately, it appears that I can only run `scalene script.py` while I need to be able to specify the module to correctly run the application with `python -m mymodule`, which I can't seem to do with scalene.

Is there a way to overcome this? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

cf [Scalene's documentation](https://pypi.org/project/scalene/) :

> `scalene your_prog.py                             # full profile (prints to console)` 
> `python3 -m scalene your_prog.py                  # equivalent alternative`

You can use the second form with Scalene.

Comment: Scalene developer here - to clarify, you can combine Scalene and PyTest using the following command (note the two `-m`s; the `---` is to end Scalene arg parsing):

`python3 -m scalene --- -m pytest your_test.py`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `runpy.run_module()` to create a wrapper around your module, which you can then profile!

`wrapper.py` might contain:

```py
from runpy import run_module
run_module('your_module_name', run_name='__main__')
```

and then you can run `scalene wrapper.py`!

The `run_name` argument is needed in order to "trick" the `if __name__ == '__main__'` clause into executing, if you have one.